# Display Today's Birthday in Block

Tags: views, datetime

I have a  Content Type 'Teams' which have name as Title field, Image field and Date of birth field using Date module.

I want to display Today's birthday in block. I've tried using views but could not achieve it.

Is it possible to display in drupal. Please Help

Comment: What Drupal version? For Drupal 7, there is the [birthdays module](https://www.drupal.org/project/birthdays).

Comment: birthday module is for user only i think

Comment: Not nescessarily. It provisides a birthday field that you should be able to place in nodes. Though in most cases it makes sense to apply this to users only. I think it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Working with Drupal 7 and Date module, if you enable Date Views sub-module, you may create a Views block with a filter criteria based on your Date field. There, you will just have to enter a relative date (now) and filter your nodes with your birthday's dates. (i.e. Date field value is equal to : now).

Hope this helps.